# Datatables "show/hide" function removes table header

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I using Datatables to create my tables. I have created a function that on button click reinitialize the table. I want to hide my table while the data are loaded, and then show the table when with all of my data.
I make this :

```
$j("#tableId").hide();
```

then when data are ready

```
$j("#tableId").Show();
```

This works ok but, when the table is reinitialized the table header is disappeared.
Do you have any example to show me what I do wrong?

Comment: Instead of hiding and showing the table, try surrounding the table in a div and hide/show the div.

Comment: ok It works now. The table header is not disappeared, but I have any one problem. When the table is reinitialized the header becomes shorter that the table body, and when I type on "search" or click "show more entries" the table header is re-rendered to its full length.
Do you have any suggestion for this?

Comment: It's hard to say without seeing more of your code. Are you able to create a jsfiddle or provide more code?

Comment: I solved it by adding this css : style="table-layout:fixed" at my table.

Comment: Awesome, glad you were able to get it fixed!